Where would Data island period take place within HDMI frame?
So this, in my understanding, is how a video frame would be transferred over HDMI. From the top left corner, visible space would be transferred line by line. Lines would be interspersed by horizontal sync period and front and back porches (I'm puzzled on why front porch is after visible space, but I assumed that they are front and back w.r.t. sync period). And separate frames would be interspersed by a vertical sync period and porches as well.

Below is a diagram I have found in a research paper.

Source:
Screen Gleaning: Exploration of the Display Cable Side-Channel
Lauret, D. (Author). 13 Jul 2021
Student thesis: Master
I'm confused on how exactly Video Data, Data and Control periods are mapped to this diagram. I know that during control period, 2 bits show whether it is currently vertical and/or horizontal sync while the other 4 indicate which type of data, video or audio/aux would follow. This originally led me to believe that control period happens at a fixed place in the transmission and with a fixed frequency. However, it is clearly not the case because the second image shows audio data being scattered all over the porches, and audio is transferred during Data period which must be announced via control packet.
So where on the diagram do control periods take place? Are there multiple control periods per line to announce both forecoming audio in the porch and video data in the following line?

Control period is transmitted when no video period or data period needs to be transmitted.
That diagram is almost identical to a similar diagram in a freely available early HDMI standard.
The red is video data period, blue is period for data islands and grey is control period.
Like you say, there must be a control period between any other period, and there is.
